# 301 Redirection from /%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html to /%postname%/

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, permalinks

I want to change the permalinks from /%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html to /%postname%/ on WordPress.

I've got hundreds of posts so I want to know please if there is any chance to make a redirection from .htacess for old my posts with /%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html to /%postname%/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the redirection using the Yoast permalink helper tool. Worked well!
https://yoast.com/research/permalink-helper.php
I added the following to my htaccess file.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+).html$ https://yourdomain.com/$3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way all your permalinks looks just by navigating the

**/wp-admin >> Settings >> Permalinks**

[image]

When you done done forget to save it.

Extra note: Changing your permalinks will hurt your SEO.

Comment: I was talking about the redirection. I got it solved by the Yoast permalink helper tool. https://yoast.com/research/permalink-helper.php